# 1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax" inserting(Another)

Tags: python, mysql, sql, database

I have the following error on my IDE:

```
MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '2102@lionstate.edu', '88zlsj5j', 'Kristopher O'Connell', '21', 'F', 'CMPSC', '77' at line 1")
```

Here is a portion of my code that causes the error:

```
for a, b, c, d, e ,f, g, h in zip(df_stu['Email'], df_stu['Password'], df_stu['Full Name'], df_stu['Age'], df_stu['Gender'], df_stu['Major'], df_stu['Street'], df_stu['Zip']):
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO LSU.Student (Semail, Spassword, Sname, Sage, Sgender, Smajor, Sstreet, Szipcode) "
                   "VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%d', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%d')" % (a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h))
```

And This is my CREATE TABLE:

```
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS LSU.Student (Semail CHAR(50), Spassword CHAR(20), Sname CHAR(50), "
               "Sage INT, Sgender CHAR(5), Smajor CHAR(50), Sstreet CHAR(50), Szipcode INT, PRIMARY KEY (Semail))")
```

This looks right to me, but the IDE keep saying that there is a syntax error.

Comment: Post the *entire* error message

Comment: LIMIT is a reserved keyword

Comment: What is the period qualifying `LSU.`? is the name of the database?

Answer (score 0):

Can the single quote (') in 'Kristopher O'Connell' be interfering with the query?

Answer (score 0):

Consider [parameterization](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+%5Bmysql%5D+parameter), the highly advised and recommended, industry best practice approach to avoid SQL injection by malicious users; quote enclosures and special characters that can break query execution; and unreadable/unmaintainable code as data mixes with code.

```
# PREPARED STATEMENT (ALL PLACEHOLDERS USING UNQUOTED %s PLACEHOLDERS, NO DATA)
sql = """INSERT INTO LSU.Student (Semail, Spassword, Sname, Sage, Sgender, Smajor, Sstreet, Szipcode)
         VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
      """

for a, b, c, d, e ,f, g, h in zip(df_stu['Email'], df_stu['Password'], df_stu['Full Name'], 
                                  df_stu['Age'], df_stu['Gender'], df_stu['Major'], 
                                  df_stu['Street'], df_stu['Zip']):    
    # QUERY EXECUTION
    cursor.execute(sql, (a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h))
```

Even consider `executemany` using pandas' [DataFrame.values](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) method as it appears you are iterating from a data frame. This avoids the `for` and `zip` loop:

```
# PREPARED STATEMENT
sql = """INSERT INTO LSU.Student (Semail, Spassword, Sname, Sage, Sgender, Smajor, Sstreet, Szipcode)
         VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
      """

# EXECUTE PARAMETERIZED QUERY
sql_cols = ['Email', 'Password', 'Full Name', 'Age', 'Gender', 'Major', 'Street', 'Zip']
cursor.executemany(sql, df_stu[sql_cols].values.tolist())   
conn.commit()
```